# Serializing Generic Class in C#

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization

i have a problem when trying to serialize an object in C# to XML.
I figured out it goes wrong when exporting this class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(CountryData))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ManufacturerData))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ProgramData))]

[Serializable()]
public class DeliveryTimeList<T> where T : IDeliveryTimeData
{
    private DataTable _data;
    public DataTable Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set { _data = value; }
    }

    public DeliveryTimeList() 
    {
        _data = new DataTable();         
    }

    public void Add(T data) 
    {
        //       Not in Use
        //_data.Rows.Add(data.ItemArray());
    }
}
```

The class is generic because the next step is to alter the DataTable at the creation of the class and it will contain a List.
The classes CountryData, Manufacturer and ProgramData implement the interface IDeliveryTimeData.

I get a System.InvalidOperationException with the following description:
Beim Generieren des XML-Dokuments ist ein Fehler aufgetreten (<- German)
which roughly translater *There was an Error during generation of the XML Document*.
I don't know why it isn't serializing but i expect that the problem has something to do with that the class is generic.

Has anybody a clue what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you set your interface IDeliveryTimeData as serializable too?

Comment: This is not possible as it seems : Error 7 Attribute 'Serializable' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, struct, enum, delegate' declarations.

Comment: Well this code compiles, yours should too if you do it correctly

    class A : IDeliveryTimeData { }
        interface IDeliveryTimeData : ISerializable
        { 
    }

Comment: Ah and yes, that is not an attribute. You need to make your interface inherits from ISerializable

Comment: Not sure if it's still a problem but I remember back in .net 2.0 you couldn't serialize a datatable, you had to serialize a dataset that it was attached to instead

Comment: @gimpycpu: that's incorrect. You only need to inherit from `ISerializable` if you want to implement custom **binary** serialization. Even the `Serializable` attribute is not needed here if `XmlSerializer` is being used.

Comment: @Kev thanks a lot this solved the problem. If you make an answer containing this you get the accepted answer points you deserve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant directly serialize a datatable, you need to serialize a dataset that it is attached to instead